# Right way to initialize React context object for sharing with components

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I wanted to create the single ApplicationContext for sharing the config in react application. So initially simple version is created as below. But considering multiple imports from different locations this would keep initializing the AppConfigContext again an again which might not be a good idea

```
import React from 'react'


let AppConfigContext = React.createContext(AppConfig)
export default AppConfigContext
```

So I updated code as below to ensure to create single instance only

```
let AppConfigContext = null
if (AppConfigContext === null) {
  AppConfigContext = React.createContext(AppConfig)
}
export default AppConfigContext
```

So I wanted to understand if this is a better way or there is even better way to achieve this? Or is this even a valid concern?

Comment: `multiple imports from different locations this would keep initializing the AppConfigContext again an again` It shouldn't. Modules only get initialized once. Did you observe that happening, or are you just assuming it would?

Comment: @NicholasTower in current scenario i don't find any side effects of it but considering object initialization looks like should happen only once after looking at both codes and logging seems both are getting initialized. Trying the singleton pattern now

Comment: Multiple Module imports ! = multiple initialization.

Comment: @NicholasTower i checked asserting it and it seems even first returns the same object so it seems modules are singleton by default